# Insert span tag inside a tag

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to insert a span tag inside a tag like this by jQuery but I can't find anything that works:

I have this:

`<div class="linkscorponoti"><a href=url target=_blank>Oficial</a></div>`

I need to insert a span tag that looks like this:

`<div class="linkscorponoti"><a href=url target=_blank><span>Oficial</span></a></div>`

I tried it but it didn't work:

`$(".linkscorponoti").find("a").add( "span" );`

Comment: Try this:

    var a = $("div.linkscorponoti a");
    $(a).html("<span>" + $(a).text() + "</span>");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.wrapInner()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) instead:

```js
$('div.linkscorponoti >a').wrapInner('<span>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="linkscorponoti"><a href=url target=_blank>Oficial</a></div>
```

This produces:

```
<div class="linkscorponoti">
  <a href="url" target="_blank">
    <span>Oficial</span>
  </a>
</div>
```